# Clear Tkinter Entry text - so new text looks new?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, message-queue, tkinter-entry

I want to modify the code below to clear the Entry text prior to new text being written.  Basically I want to delete text, wait one second, then write new text.  This should give the appearance of "NEW" text being written.
Any ideas?  TIA - Brad

```
    import thread, Queue, time, random, poster
    from Tkinter import *

    dataQueue = Queue.Queue()

    def status(t):
        try:
            data = dataQueue.get(block=False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            t.delete(0, END)
            time.sleep(1)
            t.insert(0, '%s\n' % str(data))
        t.after(2, lambda: status(t))

    def makethread():
        thread.start_new_thread(poster.poster, (1,dataQueue))    

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("240x45")
        t = Entry(root)
        t.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        Button(root, text='Start Epoch Display',
                command=makethread).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        status(t)
        root.mainloop()
```

In another file called poster

```
    import random, time

    def poster(id,que):
        while True:
            delay=random.uniform(5, 10)
            time.sleep(delay)
            que.put(' epoch=%f, delay=%f' % (time.time(), delay))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made these changes and it works...  Thanks to @anonakos.  See my comments to his answer.

```
Main code:
    else:
        t.delete(0, END)
        time.sleep(1)
        t.insert(0, '%s\n' % str(data))
    t.after(2, lambda: status(t))

Poster code:
def poster(id,que):
    while True:
        delay=random.uniform(5, 10)
        time.sleep(delay-0.5)
        que.put(' ')
        time.sleep(.5)
        que.put(' epoch=%f, delay=%f' % (time.time(), delay))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are potentially many threads writing to the queue (one for every time the button is pressed) it is a little unclear when text should be deleted and new text should be inserted. For example, if text has just been written and new text arrives, should the new text be written immediately or should it be added to a queue for later display as time permits?

You can setup the status handler to process delete commands as well as insert commands. This version of the handler starts a thread after every insert that sends back a delete command. If the ID of the delete command matches the ID of the text currently being displayed, then the status handler erases the display:

```
def status(t, current_id, queue):
    try:
        data = queue.get(block = False)

        # Insert text for ID command:
        if type(data) == tuple:
            (id, str) = data
            t.delete(0, END)
            t.insert(0, str)
            current_id = id

            # Thread that sends a delete command
            # after a fixed delay.
            make_delete_thread(id, queue)

        # Delete text for ID command:
        elif data == current_id:
            t.delete(0, END)

    except Queue.Empty:
        pass

    t.after(10, lambda: status(t, current_id, queue))

def make_delete_thread(id, queue):
    thread.start_new_thread(delete_thread, (id, queue))

def delete_thread(id, queue):
    time.sleep(1)
    queue.put(id)
```

Comment: @antanakos - first, thanks for the reply.  My code is flawed in that only ONE thread should be started with button press.  Subsequent presses should be inhibited.  Based on that, the queue would only have one source of data and a data handler probably wouldn't be necessary.  Your code was VERY helpful. I now understand that if I want to clear text, I simply put an empty sting on the queue.  I will give it a try.  Thanks - Brad

Comment: doh, putting an empty string on the queue works great.  I was trying to change insert an empty string directly; not via the queue. Thanks again - Brad